# Что такое КЛАДР?

Tags: база-данных, кладр, sql

Добрый день! В последнее время меня стал интересовать вопрос "Что такое КЛАДР и зачем он нужен?". Насколько я понял, это *типа* база данных, где содержатся области, районы, города, улицы. Еще слышал что они там лежат в дурацком формате (нарушена 1-я н/ф и т.д.) Хотел у себя на сайте сделать форму регистрации, данные местоположения берутся из БД. Или подскажите другой рабочий способ чтоб можно было брать адреса `SQL`-ем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[с января 2012 года на сайте системы fias.nalog.ru начали в еженедельном режиме выкладывать в свободный доступ базу ФИАС в двух форматах dbf и xml](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140378/)

Comment: @Gorets, ты где в [этом][1] запросе видел слово ФИАС? Еще скажи прям щас поиском нашел :-| Знаю я таких умников.. Без сарказма никак значит? Что за народ пошел :-((

[1]: http://www.google.kz/search?q=кладр+зачем+нужен&hl=ru&rlz=1C1_____enKZ482KZ482&prmd=ivns&ei=ZKCoT4OCAbHS4QTqpNTxAQ&start=10&sa=N

Comment: так я же и предлагаю научить тебя пользоваться гуглом... вот смотри на пример запроса - [вот так][1]

  [1]: http://www.google.kz/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD&hl=ru&rlz=1C1_____enKZ482KZ482&prmd=ivns&ei=ZKCoT4OCAbHS4QTqpNTxAQ&start=10&sa=N#hl=ru&rlz=1C1_____enKZ482KZ482&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...5267.5267.0.5489.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.6grDi6yOGLw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=a64b25cbbb371f3c&biw=1366&bih=667

Comment: не надо поисковик грузить оборотами и предложениями, типа "дорогой гугл, я голодный, с утра нече не ел, сейчас я в центре москвы, где тут можно покушать, а потом где можно погулять?", поиск надо делать только по ключевым словам(!) и не какого сарказма

Comment: >(!) и не какого сарказма

зачем тогда первую строку написал? Я просто хамло от людей по таким ответам и отделяю. Представляю, зайдет сюда новичок (по ссылке откуда-то что тут профи сидят), а тут ему такой превед... Разумеется сюда он больше не зайдет. Ладно я-то, за пол года разных людей тут видел :-/

Comment: ну а ты таких как я тоже пойми =) вопросы этот не такой уж и сложный, тут нету не аналитики, не проблем, не путаницы. Представь, сидят тут профи, все занятые, отвечают, тем кто, что-то делает, помогают новичкам, а тут заходит ленивый новичок, который даже погуглить поленился или просит других за него это делать, зачем он тут такой нужен? других отвлекать?

Comment: он тут не нужен, но не стоит так агрессивно реагировать. вопрос реально ниочем

Answer (score 5):

КЛАДР - классификатор адресов России, введен в действие с 01.12.2005 приказом ФНС России от 17.11.2005 № САЭ-3-13/594@ .
Для удобства работы с адресными данными разработана программа «КЛАДР - классификатор адресов России». В настоящее время доступна программа версии 5.5
Основное назначение
Программа «КЛАДР - классификатор адресов России» позволяет получить индекс по улице, найти любую адресную информацию. КЛАДР - классификатор адресов России помогает работать многим другим программам. В программу также включен справочник ОКАТО.

Comment: И вам спасибо))

Comment: Пажалуйста :)